# Elasticsearch Index wildcard Performance

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-performance

```
log-1
log-2
log-3
```

If there is an index, I use "log-"
But suppose that the data I want is only in log-1.
Is there a difference in actual operation and performance between using it as log- and using it as log-1?

Search commands will surely be executed on log-1 and log-2 indexes.
It's a command that doesn't look up anything, but what's the actual operation?

Comment: what do you mean by actual operation, if there is no documents on other documents there is not much impact on search performance.

Answer (score 0):

Documents are pre indexed before inserting.
I hope you already have proper analyzer like standard analyzer to make the searching process simpler.

In that case, the full text search should be faster.

Sometimes, its based on the type of data you store. So you should run tests based on your data and environment for the two cases you have mentioned to come up for a conclusion.